# Getting a Null value when user change a selection when click on add more anchor tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

User select single or multiple week days from dropdwon menu

here is the code

```
<table class="striped display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <?php for($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++ ){?>
        <tr id="row<?php echo $i?>">
          <td class="input-field col s2">
           <label>Week Days</label>
            <select id="week_days<?php echo $i;?>" data-rel="chosen" name="week_days<?php echo $i;?>[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                    <option value="1">Monday</option>
                    <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
                    <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
                    <option value="4">Thursday</option>
                    <option value="5">Friday</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>   
                    </tr>
       <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
<a id="more_btn" class="right" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="../../assets/images/icons/add-icon.ico" width="23px" title="Add More"/></a>
```

First time user select a single or multiple week day when click on add more anchor tag check the value of week day by alerting and this table row will be check from database using ajax if response will be equal to 1 then alert message show that **TimeTable Found** after alerting this message user change selection of weekdays then the value of weekdays will be **null** in alerting message.. so how to get the value of weekdays when user change selection of weekdays by click on add more anchor tag

Issue is that First time value of weekdays get correctly but when weekday value is exist in database then user change weekdays selection so value of weekday is null. why its getting a null value instead of 1,2,3,4,5?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var j=1;
 $('#more_btn').click(function() {
j++;
var u = j-1;
var prev_weekdays = $('#week_days'+u).val();
var weekDay_field = prev_weekdays.toString().split(",");
        var weekDay1 = weekDay_field[0];
        var weekDay2 = weekDay_field[1];
        var weekDay3 = weekDay_field[2];
        var weekDay4 = weekDay_field[3];
        var weekDay5 = weekDay_field[4];
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "check_timetable.php",
    data: {weekday: prev_weekdays},
    success: function(result) {
        var value = $.trim(result);
        if (value == "1"){
            alert('TimeTable Found');
        } else{   
alert("enter");
        }      
    },

});
});
</script>
```

Ajax calling PHP file for cheching weekday value is exist into database or not

```
<?php
 require_once("../../assets/db_connect.php");

 if(!empty($_REQUEST["weekday"])) {
$weekday = $_REQUEST['weekday'];
$weekdays;
foreach ($weekday as $WeekDay){
    $WD .= $WeekDay.",";
} $weekdays =rtrim($WD,',');


$TimeTable_Row = mysql_query( "SELECT * from tbl_timetable where week_days in (".$weekdays."));
$RowCount1 = mysql_num_rows($TimeTable_Row);
if($RowCount1>0){
    echo 1;
} else {
    echo 0; 
}
}?>
```

Comment: your query is missing a quote `(".$weekdays."));`; look at syntax highlighting, it's showing there's an error. Is that your real code?  That should read as `(".$weekdays.")");`

Comment: I resovle this syntax error but still show me null value when week day value exist into database

Comment: can you `echo $TimeTable_Row` or `var_dump($TimeTable_Row)`? Does the query look as you expect? Can you provide table schema? Also kindly update your question with the resolved syntax errors.

Comment: I also believe that you are inserting a full array of the weekday values into the mysql `in` function? That won't work either. You will have to perform an `implode()`.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM tbl_timetable  WHERE week_days IN('" . implode( "', '", $weekdays  ) . "')"`

Comment: It's going to be difficult to help aside from what has already been covered without any further information.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `val()` to read the values from a simple select or multi select.

```js
function readValues(){
console.log($("#multiSelect").val())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="multiSelect">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button onclick="readValues()">check</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for supporting.. can you read my question again carefully?

Comment: First time value of weekdays get correctly but when weekday value is exist in database then user change weekdays selection so value of weekday is null. where its getting a null value

Comment: Are you sure are checking the exact onclick function there? I see you have 5 select boxes there. Also null means no value in select input is selected, so I think you are accessing wrong select field.

Comment: why are you incrementing `j` at the beginning of click callback function?

Comment: are you new in javascript and php field??

Comment: Can you simulate the scenario somewhere?